# Android string access for database

Tags: android

hopefully a simple question here, i have a barcode scanner using Zxing, this is an extract of the code(class1). I am trying to hook this up with a datbase(class2). How can i use the ("SCAN_RESULT"). In my database class think i am vaugly on the right lines but can't seem to comlete it!

Class1

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            contents.?????


            Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.new.data");
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);
```

Class2

```
  String b_code = ?????;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Barcode", b_code));
```

Any ideas on how to begin taking this from one class to another?

Help greatly appriciated!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
intent2.putExtra("keyName", contents);
```

to send contents as string with intent and access in the other class with

```
String contents = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");
```

Comment: Awsome Thanks Very much, was struggling with this!! Many Thanks